# Mac insomnia: Finding what's keeping my Mac up within console?

Tags: sleep, macbook-pro, osx-mavericks

I have a 15" rMBP from late 2013 and it's been great.

However, I have noticed there are times where I will shut the lid and the system will simply not go to sleep. Many times I am packing it after a day at work and shut it only to get home and find my bag very warm because the device is still on and running.

I know that if something's actively using the disk, it will keep the system up and running. That's useful sometimes but even last night I didn't have a single application open and it was still 'awake' when I got up in the morning.

Is there anything from within OSX to determine what's using the disk, or what's holding the system from going into sleep?